# Some pages blank in newest questions list?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was just looking through some old questions (via the 'Questions'->'newest' tab) and found that pages 23, 24, 25, 26 and 27 are all blank. I suspect it's a bug. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

I can repro, which is very much appreciated, as this is a recurrence of a bug we've seen before but has been elusive to repro. I have downloaded the in-memory cache-dump for local analysis; thanks for your report - it will genuinely help us fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see it too, with

- no ignored tags (if you have ignored tags set and set to be undisplayed instead of dimmed, you can in principle get this effect as [status-by-design])
- 15 posts per page (I think you're must the the same or there would only be fewer than 20 pages)
- Firefox 9.0.1 on Mac OS 10.5.8
- The freehand circle editor but no other userscripts active